# how to create html field with a dropdown attached to it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

Could anybody please tell me that how do I create an HTML field with a dropdown attached to it at the end of the field like in the image below:[click here to see an example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URWnk.png)

I am actively looking for your kind help. Thanks

My Tried code:

```
    <form action = "Controller" method = "GET" class="form-wrapper">

    <input type = "hidden" name="command" value="search"/>

    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for..." required class="form-control">
    <input type="submit" value="go" id="submit" class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm">

    <div style="float: left;">

        <a href="javascript:showhide('uniquename')" style="margin-left: 2px;"> search criteria </a>

        <div id="uniquename" style="display: none; float: center;">
            <select name="choice">
                <option>Document</option>
                <option>Author</option>
                <option>Writer</option>
                <option>Contributor</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

Result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb3cA.png)

Comment: where is your tried code?

Comment: I just post the code Ivin Raj

Comment: where is it? @badshah Tracker

Comment: I added the code @Iven Raj

Comment: Thanks it's working but can you please tell me how do i design as I posted the image in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
<title>Create a Drop Down Menu with Search Box in CSS3 and HTML</title>
 <link href="https://designmodo.com/demo/dropdown-menu-search/flatnav.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="nav">
  
  <li id="search">
   <form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search"/>
    <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button"></a>
   </form>
  </li>
  <li id="options">
   <a href="#">Options</a>
   <ul class="subnav">
    <li><a href="#">Document</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Author</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Writer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contributor</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>

 <script src="https://designmodo.com/demo/dropdown-menu-search/prefixfree-1.0.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ivin Raj 
It worked for mine perfectly.

Comment: It's my pleasure sir @BadshahTracker

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one: remove `Style Display:none;`

```
 <form action = "Controller" method = "GET" class="form-wrapper">

    <input type = "hidden" name="command" value="search"/>

    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for..." required class="form-control">
    <input type="submit" value="go" id="submit" class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm">

    <div style="float: left;">

        <a href="javascript:showhide('uniquename')" style="margin-left: 2px;"> search criteria </a>

        <div id="uniquename" style="float: center;">
            <select name="choice">
                <option>Document</option>
                <option>Author</option>
                <option>Writer</option>
                <option>Contributor</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

[**Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/6aa4zp2w/1/)